# Why not to copy a class consisting of a single shared_ptr

Tags: c++, copy, move, shared-ptr

Recently, I read [an article](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/04/21/getting-lazy-with-c/) about lazy data structures in C++ (this question is not about lazy, or the particular data structure, though - it is just the motivation).

A lazy stream (list) is implemented as follows:

```
template<class T>
class Stream
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr <Susp<Cell<T>>> _lazyCell;
public:
    Stream() {}
    Stream(std::function<Cell<T>()> f)
        : _lazyCell(std::make_shared<Susp<Cell<T>>>(f))
    {}
    Stream(Stream && stm)
        : _lazyCell(std::move(stm._lazyCell))
    {}
    Stream & operator=(Stream && stm)
    {
        _lazyCell = std::move(stm._lazyCell);
        return *this;
    }
    bool isEmpty() const
    {
        return !_lazyCell;
    }
    T get() const
    {
        return _lazyCell->get().val();
    }
    Stream<T> pop_front() const
    {
        return _lazyCell->get().pop_front();
    }
};
```

The author mentions the move constructor:

> I also added a move constructor and a move assignment operator for efficiency.

However, due to the explicit presence, one cannot simply assign a `Stream`. What is the motivation behind this?

As far as I can tell, the class consists solely of a `shared_ptr`, which can be trivially copied. Is there any benefit in forbidding copy-construction in such a class?

Comment: `shared_ptr` is not trivially copyable.

Comment: No, it sounds like a rhetorical question: What is the purpose of sharing when it is unique anyway?

Comment: @Barry: Why not? I thought that was the whole purpose of a shared_ptr?

Comment: @choeger Trivially copyable basically that you can copy an object via memcpy. You can't do that for `shared_ptr`, you need to increment the reference count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shared_ptr` is used internally to share lazy value cells as part of the private implementation.

However, from the user's point of view, it's an immutable object. Providing a copy constructor and assignment operator would undo this immutability.

He is modelling Haskell's immutable object's behaviour.

If it were thread-safe to do so, it would be reasonable to make this object copyable since in reality it's a handle to an (albeit more complex than usual) shared impl.

However, copyers would need to understand that they were copying a handle to shared state, and not state itself.

Comment: So you are saying, although it is _implemented_ like a ref, it is not meant to be used as such. That is indeed insightful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a type of premature optimization.

First of all, due to the rule of three/five (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), the move copy/assignment constructors would have been created in the same way without typing it out.

Therefore the only difference is, as you already pointed out, the missing copy/assigment constructor. It would have been better practice to mark them as deleted, e.g.:

```
 Stream(Stream & stm) = deleted;
```

However the real problem here is using a shared pointer with only a single owner. It would have been much better to just use a `std::unique_ptr`. With its use copy and assignment are disabled automatically and the intent of the author is much clearer.